# MatLab (presented data)

Tags: matlab

I have imported the data from MATLAB file contains these variables:

```
X is 1x25 double vector

A = 100

B = 62.3000

Y is 50x25 Matrix
```

I want to present the data on a scatter plot.

Comment: That's nice. What is your question? Is [`scatter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) not sufficient?

Comment: Error using scatter (line 78)
X and Y must be vectors of the same length.

Comment: Yes, the documentation pretty clearly states that `X` and `Y` need to be vectors of the same length. `Y` is a matrix, which does not meet that criteria. So you need to figure out what you want to do with `Y`. Plot every row? Random rows? Every other row?

Comment: Well, of course they have to be the same length! How do you expect to plot them if they have different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a vector as the first input to `plot` and a matrix (with a dimension which matches the size of the first vector) as the second input and it will create a plot for each pairing of the first vector and each row/column of the second input.

```
plot(X, Y, 'o')
```

[image]

This will automatically color each row of `Y` differently. If you'd like the entire plot to be the same color, you can specify the color when creating the plot

```
plot(X, Y, 'o', 'Color', 'black')
```

[image]

If, however, you want to use `scatter`, you'll need to make sure that the two inputs have the same size. You can do this by applying `repmat` to `X` to make it the same size as `Y`

```
xx = repmat(X, size(Y, 1), 1);
scatter(xx(:), Y(:))
```

[image]